# How to get the effect of bluring what's under titleBar with material based background

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Im playing with visual effects of `macOS` windows using `SwiftUI`. I created a simple App with `WindowGroup` and applied `material` background under it using `NSVisualEffectView` with `underWindowBackground` material and `behindWindow` blending mode. The background is added `ignoring safe area` and `windowGroup` is configured with `windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)` and `windowToolbarStyle(.unified(showsTitle: true))`. The effect of this is more or less something like that: [image]

Now in the next step I would like to achieve some better look for the content when it's scrolled. Right now it looks like that:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is one of the two:

1. When I scroll the ScrollView, the `WindowGroup` changes `windowStyle` to 'titleBar'
   or
2. There is additional material behind the titleBar that blurs the contend behind it, but doesn't show at all when there is nothing behind it.

I would prefer the first solution, but I couldn't find a way to do it nicely in `SwiftUI`. If you can suggest the solution please help.

Here's some parts of the code:

```
    var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ZStack {
            VisualEffectView(material: .underWindowBackground, blendingMode: .behindWindow).ignoresSafeArea() // Background
            ContentView(vmLibrary: .shared)
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth:  Self.minimumResolution.width,
            minHeight: Self.minimumResolution.height
        )
    }
    .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    .windowToolbarStyle(.unified(showsTitle: true))
    .defaultSize(Self.defaultResolution)
    .commands(content: windowCommands)
}



struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    let material: NSVisualEffectView.Material
    let blendingMode: NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode
    let state: NSVisualEffectView.State
    
    init(material: NSVisualEffectView.Material = .contentBackground, blendingMode: NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode = .withinWindow, state: NSVisualEffectView.State = .followsWindowActiveState) {
        self.material = material
        self.blendingMode = blendingMode
        self.state = state
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        NSVisualEffectView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ view: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        view.material = material
        view.blendingMode = blendingMode
        view.state = state
    }
    
}
```

As an example I can paste a gif of how Finder does it. This kind of behavior would be what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]